# Unable to find certificate from store when the client app is published but works locally

Tags: c#, certificate

When I run this locally, it successfully finds the `certificate` from the `smart card` , reads it and signs the document.

If I publish this part of the app on a `client side`, run it on `IIS` using `https` and then I run the whole `application` on `localhost` and connect it to the `client side app` it successfully connects to it but then the number of `certificates` are 0.

Unfortunately because it is `client side` I can only use `logs` and not `debug`.

So far I have established that there are no `certs` that match the `thumbprint` on the `certificate`. However, again locally it finds the `certificate` by the `thumprint`.

I have tried to change the `X509Store` `StoreName` to `StoreName.Root`, `StoreName.CertificationAuthority`, but it can never find the `cert` that I am looking for.

```
    public (InvoiceResult resultValue, X509Certificate2 cert) GetDefaultCertificateStoredOnTheCard()
    {

        var resultValue = InvoiceResult.Success;
        using X509Store x509Store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        X509Store store = x509Store;
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);

        // by thumbprint, there is only one
        certs = certs.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, Settings.Default.Thumbprint, true);

        _log.TraceInformation($"Locations of certs in store after opening flags is {certs.Count}!");

        if (certs.Count == 0)
        {
            resultValue = InvoiceResult.CannotFindSignature;
            // throw new ArgumentException("Please insert smart card to obtain certificate.");
        }
        X509Certificate2 cert = certs[0];
        if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
        {
            // software cert
            _ = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        }
        else
        {
            // certificate from smartcard
            CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider")
            {
                Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer
            };
            _ = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        }
        _log.TraceInformation($"GetDefaultCerticateStoredOnTheCard method gets values {cert}.");
        _log.TraceInformation($"GetDefaultCerticateStoredOnTheCard method gets values {resultValue}.");

        return (resultValue, cert);
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the account your application is running under doesn't have the permissions to read the certificate from the store.

Open your certificate store in MMC. Right-click the certificate and pick All tasks > Manage private keys (note: I have Windows 7 on my machine here; it might be different in other versions of Windows). Then you can assign read permissions to the correct user account.

Comment: Hi howcheng. I  cannot export the certificate with the private key as it is from a smart card. How it works now - it uses IDPrimePKCS11.dll to read the cert from the smart card , uses the private key to sign with the digital signature. On localhost they both work. 
Once I publish it does not.. Maybe it is permissions on the folder?

Comment: I enabled SSL on IIS, when I ran it on the first instance, it asked for the certificate in the browser, I chose the certificate , put the PIN but it still did not work. The log showed the number of certs were 0 in the store.localuser.

I am just wondering... is there a way with IIS to obtain the cert from the smart card or add it to local store somehow?

Comment: Well of course the number of certs in store.localuser will be zero because the cert is on the smart card. I still think it's a permissions issue where the IIS user doesn't have rights to read the smart card or the file itself.